# JS: Add a value and attach to link

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to add +1 (or -1) to a span and then attach the value to the an href.

This is my code:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var valueElement = $('#value');
    function incrementValue(e) {
        valueElement.text(Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment, 0));
        calculateLink();
        return false;
    }
    $('#plus').bind('click', { increment: 1 }, incrementValue);
    $('#minus').bind('click', { increment: -1 }, incrementValue);

    function calculateLink() {
        var value1 = document.getElementById('value').innerText;
        var value2 = document.getElementById('valueone').innerText;
        var value3 = document.getElementById('valuetwo').innerText;

        var url = "deskshop3.aspx?item1=" + value1.text + "&item2=" + value2.text + "&item3=" + value3.text;
        var element = document.getElementById('cashierLink');
        element.setAttribute("href", url)
    }

});
```

Now, what happens is that I am capable of changing the value of "value" span by pressing plus and minus buttons, but whenever I press the href "cashierLink" it always sends the default values of "value", "valueone" and "valuetwo" that the page loaded with.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Arseney

Comment: Have you tried seeing if there are any console errors in the debugger?  What is `value1.text`, those value's should just be strings, not objects with a `.text` attribute.

Comment: You are right. That was a last moment mistake. However changing it to just "valueone" didn't change the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `valueElement` is getting its text changed first, but then during the `calculateLink()` call, you are trying to assign a url using `value1.text`. However, `value1` does not have a `.text` property since it is a string and not an object.  This causes an error during execution and ends up bailing out of the code early, which explains why the value element changes visually, yet your href value is incorrect.

Try doing this for your URL instead:

```
var url = "deskshop3.aspx?item1=" + value1 + "&item2=" + value2 + "&item3=" + value3;
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote "text" twice by mistake. I've changed it to what you wrote but results are the same.

Comment: Do you actually read the query string on initialization of the deskshop3.aspx page for the values item1, item2, and item3 and then apply them?

Comment: Thanks man. I've found my problem. value2 and value1 were null (their visibility was false, I didn't know this turns them null).
So now that I first check if they are not null before using them, everything works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the way you wanna do it, but you should try to use global variables instead of text value from an element. I made a JSFiddle to show you what it could look like, you can change it the way you want to.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/r0w4wfvw/)

```
/// global variables ///

var valCount = 0;
var value1 = ['first value', 'second value', 'third value'];
var value2 = ['first 2nd value', 'second 2nd value', 'third 2nd value'];
var value3 = ['first 3rd value', 'second 3rd value', 'third 3rd value'];

////////////////////////

$('#plus').bind('click', function(){ calculateLink(); });
$('#minus').bind('click', function(){ calculateLink(true); });

function calculateLink(minus) {

    if(minus){
        if(valCount == 0)
        valCount = (value1.length-1);
        else
        valCount--;
    } else{
        if(valCount == (value1.length-1))
        valCount = 0;
        else
        valCount++;
    }

    var url = "deskshop3.aspx?item1=" + value1[valCount] +
        "&item2=" + value2[valCount] +
        "&item3=" + value3[valCount];

    document.getElementById('cashierLink').setAttribute("href", url);
}
```